# How to say change from A to B

Tags: verbs

Is it:

> AはBに変わる。

If I want to say A changes to B

Thanks

Comment: So, did you mean "A changes to B" or "A changes into B"? What's the context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual phrase would be:

> 「A + **から** + B + **に** + 変{か}わる」

if you are talking about a change from an old state to a new state.

Your phrase:

> 「A + **は** + B + **に** + 変わる」

means more like:

> "A changes into B."